# C++ 17 How to specialize static function template in class template

Tags: c++, templates

How to do this in G++?

- Declare a class template ss.          [ok]
- Decalre a static function template f  [ok]
- How to specialize f  ?                [error]

This code is ok for VC++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
#include<typeinfo>

template<typename T> 
struct ss
{
    template<typename F>
    static constexpr auto f()
    {
        printf("template !\n");
    }

    template<>
    static constexpr auto f<int>()
    {
        printf("int !\n");
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
   return ss<int>::f<char>();
}
```

online : https://godbolt.org/z/qGq6bP

```
source>:14:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct ss<T>'
   14 |     template<>
      |              ^
<source>:15:34: error: template-id 'f<int>' in declaration of primary template
   15 |     static constexpr auto f<int>()
      |                                  ^
<source>: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
<source>:24:27: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   24 |    return ss<int>::f<char>();
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:14:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct ss<T>'
   14 |     template<>
      |              ^
<source>:15:34: error: template-id 'f<int>' in declaration of primary template
   15 |     static constexpr auto f<int>()
      |                                  ^
<source>: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
<source>:24:27: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
   24 |    return ss<int>::f<char>();
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
Execution build compiler
```

Comment: I belive the issue is about returning void value from main function.

Comment: *"error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope"* means "explicit specializations must be done in namespace scope" (it really does work on VS though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is GCC's issue. According to [CWG 727](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue727), explicit specialization should be allowed in any scope, including in class scope.

> An explicit specialization may be declared in any scope in which the corresponding primary template may be defined (*N4868*.9.8.2.3 [namespace.memdef], 11.4 [class.mem], 13.7.3 [temp.mem]).

To make it working with GCC, you have to put the explicit specialization in namespace scope, that means you have to explicitly specialize the containing class template `ss` at the same time too. Or you can use function template helper, e.g.

```
template <typename F>
constexpr auto foo() 
{
    printf("template !\n");
}
template <>
constexpr auto foo<int>() 
{
    printf("int !\n");
}

template<typename T> 
struct ss
{
    template<typename F>
    static constexpr auto f()
    {
        return foo<F>();
    }

};
```